# How to override = symbol while converting HashMap to String using toString method?

Tags: java, hashmap, tostring, println

Below is part of code where map is initialized as:
`Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();`
and the line which I want to modify the output is

`System.out.println("Price and items "+map.toString());`

where the output presently is

 **{100=10,200=5}**

I want to display
**{100:10,200:5}**

Comment: You can't. You have to implement your own method.

Comment: You should not be using `toString()` for production code, only for debugging. Create your own output method.

Comment: you can use string format function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't rely on the method `toString()` as **it is an implementation detail** that could change from one version of Java to another, you should rather implement your own method.

Assuming that you use **Java 8**, it could be:

```
public static <K, V> String mapToString(Map<K, V> map) {
    return map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}"));
}
```

If you want to have **the exact same implementation** as `AbstractMap#toString()` that checks if the key or the value is the current map, the code would then be:

```
public static <K, V> String mapToString(Map<K, V> map) {
    return map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(
            entry -> (entry.getKey() == map ? "(this Map)" : entry.getKey())
                    + ":"
                    + (entry.getValue() == map ? "(this Map)" : entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}"));
}
```

Comment: Watch out - this doesn't work quite the same as `HashMap.toString()` (admittedly in some pretty marginal cases). Check out the source of `AbstractMap.toString()` to see what I mean.

Comment: Do you mean `key   == this ? "(this Map)" : key` or `value == this ? "(this Map)" : value`? If so it is only to avoid infinite loop as it would call `map.toString()` again which is not applicable in this case as it uses a dedicated method

Comment: I do - but what I mean is that OP asks only to change `=` to `:`, so you should preserve the existing behaviour with respect to self-keyed (or self-valued) entries.

Answer (score 2):

Since map is integer integer you can play with the `toString()` method and replace the undesired chars...

do string replace :)

```
map.toString().replace("=",":");
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you've got `=` in your keys or values.

Comment: Prefer `.replace('=', ':')`, since it avoids String literals and doesn't user Regex.

Comment: @Tom `replace` *never* uses regex.

Comment: @AndyTurner You might want to check the implementation of it ;). It internally uses `Pattern` with the provided String as a pattern literal. So it still compiles that "regex" (even though it isn't handled as a regex).

Comment: @Tom interesting. I'd not spotted that.

Comment: @AndyTurner `replace(char, char)` on the other hand works on that internal char array, which should be faster. But we're talking about milli and nano seconds, I know :D.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override the symbols in the `toString()` method directly.

Whilst you can use `String.replace` for maps where the keys and values can't contain `=` (like `Integer`s), you'd have to provide a different implementation in general.

You can see this isn't too tricky to do if you look at the source of [`AbstractMap.toString()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractMap.java#AbstractMap.toString%28%29):

```
public String toString() {
    Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
    if (! i.hasNext())
        return "{}";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('{');
    for (;;) {
        Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
        K key = e.getKey();
        V value = e.getValue();
        sb.append(key   == this ? "(this Map)" : key);
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(value == this ? "(this Map)" : value);
        if (! i.hasNext())
            return sb.append('}').toString();
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
```

You can just change the `=` to `:`.